# how to determine if all parameters are not empty

Tags: vb.net, function

I'm currently making this function/sub in order to add a user into the database, now my initial approach works, however; I believe this isn't the best solution. Are there any better ways to do this? Thanks pros!

```
Public Sub addNewSystemUser(_username As String, _password As String, _name As String, _restricionName As String)
    If _username <> String.Empty And _password <> String.Empty And _
     _name <> String.Empty And _restricionName <> String.Empty Then
        'SQL Execution here
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: You could check these things before calling the method in the first place. Or check them in the method? It's your choice in how and what you would want to handle at those times.... Also this would be best to go on the other site as it's asking about review and not a specific programming question. http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

To make the code a bit easier to read (only my opinion of course) You could try this

```
Public Sub addNewSystemUser(_username As String, _password As String, _name As String, _restricionName As String)

    dim isUsernameOK as boolean = (_username<>string.empty)
    dim isPasswordOK as boolean = (_password<>string.empty)
    dim isRestricionNameOK as boolean = (_restricionName<>string.empty)
    dim isNameOK as boolean = (_Name<>string.empty)

    If isUsernameOK and isPasswordOK And isRestricionOK and isNameOK And isRestricionNameOK Then
        'SQL Execution here
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should validator Like,
"Required Field Validator" on your respective page/form,So you can minimize your work.

I mean you can take,

RequiredFieldValidator Control

The RequiredFieldValidator control ensures that the required field is not empty. It is generally tied to a text box to force input into the text box.

The syntax of this control is as given:

```
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvemp" 
   runat="server" ControlToValidate ="ddlemp"
   ErrorMessage="Please choose a Employee" 
   InitialValue="Please choose a Employee">

</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```

Hope You get what I actually mean about validations.

Regards